# The argument to DbIsNullExpression must refer to a primitive or reference type

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
var offices=  from x in _officeRepository.GetAll()
                      select new OfficeModels()
                                 {
                                     Id = x.id,
                                     AddressOne = x.address_1,
                                     AddressTwo = x.address_2,
                                     Company = x.a1.Select(y => new CompanyModels { Id=y.id, Name = y.name}).FirstOrDefault()??
                                                x.a2.Select(y => new CompanyModels { Id = y.id, Name = y.name }).FirstOrDefault() ??
                                                x.a3.Select(y => new CompanyModels { Id = y.id, Name = y.name }).FirstOrDefault() ??
                                                x.a4.Select(y => new CompanyModels { Id = y.id, Name = y.name }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                     City = x.city,
                                     Active = x.active,
                                     Country = x.country,
                                     Deleted = x.deleted,
                                     OfficeFax = x.fax,
                                     OfficeName = x.office_name,
                                     OfficePhone = x.office_phone
                                 };
```

i'm getting this error `The argument to DbIsNullExpression must refer to a primitive or reference type`, the error is because of the CompanyModels.. what i'm doing wrong here, am i missing something ??

And if suppose i include this line while initializing CompanyModels

```
new CompanyModels { CompanyId = y.id, Name = y.name,CompType = Enumerations.Companies.MediaSellers }
```

i.e `CompType = Enumerations.Companies.MediaSellers` this gives some kind a different error saying `The specified value is not an instance of type 'Edm.Int32'Parameter name: value`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this exception tries to tell. I think that EF can only apply the ?? operator to a mapped object, because everything must be translated into SQL. It has not information of CompanyModels, so it does not know what to do with it.

If so, I think you can solve it by first setting a property, say A, like this:

```
...
AddressTwo = x.address_2,
A = x.a1.FirstOrDefault() ?? x.a2.FirstOrDefault() ?? 
    x.a3.FirstOrDefault() ?? x.a4.FirstOrDefault(),
...
```

and giving the `OfficeModels` class a Company property like this:

```
public CompanyModels Company
{
    get
    {
        return A != null ? new CompanyModels {Id = A.id, Name = A.name} : null;
    }
}
```

(I got a similar query working).

As for the second question: EF can not handle enums, so you'll have to work with integers there. Look around here at Stack Overflow for EF + enum work-arounds.